# React Pass history to a component defined in the Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this Router in my App.js:

```
<Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE || '/MyApp'}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/editProject" /*render={(props) => <ProjectEdit {...props} history={props.history} />}*/ component={ProjectEdit} />
                    {/*<Redirect path="*" to="/" />*/}
                </Switch>
            </Router>
```

From HomePage component I'm using < ProjectsList> component which have < Project> components.
Within the < Project> component I have an option of the menu for Editing a project and I'm trying to use there:

```
 <OverflowMenuItem itemText="Edit" href="#" onClick={ () => this.props.history.push('/editProject')}/>
```

But I'm getting that props is undefined!

## Resolution:

I passed the props.history as a prop `history= {this.props.history}` in this order:

**HomePage** -> **ProjectsList** -> **Project**

Comment: can you add your homepage component?I believe you are not passing props to child components

Comment: Correct. I was passing it from one place in the code and missed it from other one.

Comment: can i add an answer so that you can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Answer (score 11):

If you are working with a Functional Component, you can simply access the history instance object within your component using the `useHistory` hook, as stated on the React-Router [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory).

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

If you are working with a Class Component, you can wrap your component with `withRouter`, and then access the history object within your component

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { history } = this.props;

    return <OverflowMenuItem itemText="Edit" href="#" onClick={ () => history.push('/editProject')}/>;
  }
}

export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

Comment: I tried using it inside the Project component from inside a function -redirectToEditProject- (cause the call to ProjectEdit is from there) but got: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Are you suggesting to convert my component to functional component?

Comment: @zbeedatm oh, right. So you are using a class component. In that case, I would recommend wrapping your component with `withRouter` as a Higher Order Component? From there, you can access the history object. i have updated my demo.

Comment: Saved my bacon the night before a deadline. THANKS!

Comment: withRouter for the class component worked, thanks!