# React: this.props.location.pathname is undefined

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, location, react-router-dom, pathname

Tell me how to access `pathname`?
Parameter `this.props` is empty and `this.props.location` is undefined.

How to automatically get this parameter without having to set it yourself?

Most of the solutions found require me to set this parameter myself (manually), which is not very convenient and complicates the code.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </BrowserRouter>
  document.getElementById('root')
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row><GeneralMenu /></Row>
      <Row>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/block1">
            <PageStrategy />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/block2">
            <PageStrategy />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

class GeneralMenu  extends Component {
    render() {
// {location} = this.props.location.pathname;
      return (
  <Navbar>
    <Nav activeKey = {this.props.location.pathname}>
      <Nav.Link href = "/block1">Block1</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href = "/block2">Block2</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar>
        );      
    }
}
```

Comment: can it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253277/react-router-v4-how-to-get-current-route

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Pass history to a component defined in the Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453964/react-pass-history-to-a-component-defined-in-the-router)

Comment: @Nikita Madeev, helped `withRouter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `withRouter()` HOC in your `GeneralMenu` in this way:

```
export default withRouter(GeneralMenu);
```

and then use the exported element.

You can also do something like this, without export the element:

```
const WithRouterGeneralMenu = withRouter(GeneralMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Nav activeKey = {window.location.pathname}>
```

this option works!

And

```
<Nav.Link as = {Link} to = "/block1">
```

instead

```
<Nav.Link href = "/block1">
```

for site speed