# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following problem trying to hide the header, footer and aside for my login page

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Routes from './routes';


    export default class App extends Component {
      render(){
    
        return(
        <div>
        {this.location.pathname==='/Login' ? null:
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <Routes />
            <Footer />
        </div>
        }
        </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

I get this error message
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

How can I prevent my header, aside, footer from being shown on my login page?

Helpe please.

Comment: Did you Google this? There's a whole bunch of posts on SO about hiding stuff on certain routes. Here's top search result as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777333/react-hide-a-component-on-a-specific-route

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: this.props.location.pathname is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215266/react-this-props-location-pathname-is-undefined)

Comment: You need to use this `this.props.location.pathname`. `location` object is available via props

Answer (score 0):

## Issue(s)

`pathname` is undefined because you've not correctly accessed it from the (presumably) passed `location` prop from [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props). You've missed the `props` part.

```
this.location.pathname
```

It also appears you are attempting to read `Route` state from `App`. In order for route props to work you need to wrap your `App` component in a `Router` higher up in the react tree and render `App` into a `Route`, wrap `App` with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component, or render a `Router` *in* `App` and render your header and footer into routes so they can check the location.

## Solution

Render a `Router` around the app content. Render the header and footer into routes on the `render` prop and check the `location.pathname` and conditionally render each.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route
          render={(props) =>
            location.pathname !== "/Login" ? <Header /> : null
          }
        />
        <Routes />
        <Route
          render={(props) =>
            location.pathname !== "/Login" ? <Footer /> : null
          }
        />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

## Alternative solution

Similar to above but defer the `location.pathname` check to the components. Render the header and footer on the `component` prop and check the passed route props.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route component={Header} />
        <Routes />
        <Route component={Footer} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Example check in `Header`

```
const Header = ({ location }) => {
  ...
  return location.pathname !== "/login" ? (
    ... // header UI JSX
  ) : null;
};
```