# caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname') (React)

Tags: reactjs

[image: [enter image description here]()]

1. that error is not related to browserrouter otherwise it has to affect everywhere.
2. I have searched with pathname but is not used in that component
   Please anyone help.
   Not getting root cause of it.

Comment: does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585651/×-typeerror-cannot-read-property-pathname-of-undefined

Comment: Please show the codebase, how are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

I got this by uninstalling node_modules,  and resinstalling it.