# Pass state from one react page to another using history.push

Tags: reactjs, router

I have a search component calling my API, I want to pass that data into the results page. Instead, I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

I have tried looking all over online for solutions but it would not solve my issue. what am I doing wrong?

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Results from './Results';
import Search from './Search';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />






      <Router>
      <div>

        <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Search} />
        <Route  path='/results' render={(props)=> (
          <Results {...props}  />)} />

        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
    </header>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

search component:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class  Search extends React.Component {


    constructor() {
      super();
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.state = { 
                      search:'',
                      data:''
                    };
    }

    myChangeHandler = (event) => {
      let nam = event.target.name;
      let val = event.target.value;
      this.setState({[nam]: val});


    }



    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log("hit");
      event.preventDefault();


      fetch('http://localhost:8080/test/get/' + this.state.search,{
      method: 'GET',
      mode:'cors'}).then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({data:data}));

      console.log(this.state.data);
      this.props.history.push({pathname:'/Results',
       state: {
           data:this.state.data }}); // <--- The page you want to redirect your user to.
    }


  render(){
    return (
     <div>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="search"
                  label="search"

                  id="search"

                  onChange={this.myChangeHandler}

                /> 
                <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={this.handleSubmit}

              >
                Search
              </Button>
              <h2>{this.state.search}</h2>
              </div>

    );
  }
  }

  export default withRouter(Search)
```

results component:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Search from './Search';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
class  Results extends React.Component {


    constructor() {
        const location = useLocation;
      super();
      this.state = { 

                      data:this.props.location.state.data
                    };
    }

    myChangeHandler = (event) => {
      let nam = event.target.name;
      let val = event.target.value;
      this.setState({[nam]: val});


    }




  render(){
    return (
     <div>
              <h2>{console.log(this.state.data)}</h2>
              </div>

    );
  }
  }

  export default withRouter(Results)
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Pass history to a component defined in the Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453964/react-pass-history-to-a-component-defined-in-the-router)

Comment: Following up, it should be `this.props.history.location.state`, if you are wondering.

Comment: @wentjun i get this error when i change it to that , TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Comment: @yiby32 - `props` will be undefined in your case, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`useLocation` is a hook that is nothing but a function so you should use it this way:

```
const location = useLocation();
```

but you're trying to use hooks inside a class-based component and that's incorrect.

Coming to the actual problem your constructor should look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: props.location.state.data
  };
}
```

When using a constructor in any component you should do the same.

Comment: i get the fllowing error after trying your method: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: Try using `props.history.location.state.data`, make sure that you're calling `super(props)` wherever the constructors are used. If nothing works then create a stackblitz or codesandbox of your app.

Comment: even with the history it is giving me error. im trying to do console.log(this.state.data)